# Shortcode not returning two of the same attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

So for some reason, I'm unable to pull in the same link attributes and pass them inside my code.

So here is the shortcode:

`[slide headline="<h2>Title</h2>" image="https://via.placeholder.com/150" body="The text in the body" link="Test1|https://www.test1.com" link="Test2|https://test2.com"]`

`var_dump($atts)` just returns one link as shown below:

```
array (size=4)
  'headline' => string '</p>
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>' (length=29)
  'image' => string 'https://www.raritanheadwaters.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/placeholder-picture-large-opt.png' (length=94)
  'body' => string 'The text in the body' (length=202)
  'link' => string 'Test1|https://www.test1.com' (length=61)
```

So here is the code that I have:

```
function slide_item_shortcode($atts, $content = null)
{
    shortcode_atts([
            "image" => '',
            "headline" => '',
            "body" => '',
            "link" => '',
        ], $atts);

    var_dump($atts);

    $social_links = explode("|", $atts['link']);

    return '<li class="slide">
            <p><img src="' . esc_url($atts['image']) . '" alt="" /></p>
            <p>'. $atts['headline'] .'</p>
            <p>'. $atts['body'] .'</p>
            <p>'. '<a href="' . $social_links[1] . '" target="_blank">' . $social_links[0] . '</a>' .'</p>
            </li>';
}
add_shortcode('slide', 'slide_item_shortcode');
```

Comment: You can not pass the same name attribute in the shortcode.

Comment: What would be an alternative @Bhautik, would I pass in more parameters in the link attribute?

Comment: Do you want to pass multiple links?

Comment: You could pass two comma separated links in the attribute and later use `explode()`

Comment: I just need one link per title, so something like this link="Title1|Link1|Title2|Link2" and have that be rendered properly in my <a>.

Comment: You could use the attribute like this: `links="Test1|https://www.test1.com,Test2|https://www.test2.com"` and later explode on `,` and then on `|`

Comment: @jrswgtr, actually that's an amazing idea!

Comment: @jrswgtr Should I do two explodes or just one?

Comment: Wait a minute, I'll write an answer for you

Comment: you need to use explode function to get separate value by a comma.

Comment: @jrswgtr - Thanks so much for the help guys! Looking forward to seeing the example jrswgtr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass multiple links by using an extra explode on a different character

```
[slide ... links="Test1|https://www.test1.com,Test2|https://www.test2.com"]
```

```php
function slide_item_shortcode($atts, $content = null)
{
    shortcode_atts([
        "image" => '',
        "headline" => '',
        "body" => '',
        "links" => '',
    ], $atts);
    
    $linkPairs = explode(',', $atts['links']); // separate the pairs
    $output = '<li class="slide">';
    
    foreach($linkPairs as $linkPair) {
        $pair = explode('|', $linkPair); // separate the title and url
        $output .= 
            '<p><img src="' . esc_url($atts['image']) . '" alt="' . $pair[0] .'" /></p>
             <p>'. $atts['headline'] .'</p>
             <p>'. $atts['body'] .'</p>
             <p>'. '<a href="' . $pair[1] . '" target="_blank">' . $pair[0] . '</a>' .'</p>';
    }

    $output .= '</li>';
    
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks @jrswgtr! So now I have a return statement as shown here: `    return '<li class="slide">
            <p>'. '<a href="' . esc_url($socialLinks[0]) . '" target="_blank">' . $socialLinks[1] . '</a>' .'</p>
            </li>';` - This return is right below that code - Would I have to loop through the array?

Comment: Yes you'll have to. Wait a minute i'll adapt my answer to your function

Comment: Thanks so much man! This has saved me, looking forward to seeing the example.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help man! So this is the return that I receive on the slide with the multiple links:

<li class="slide"><p><img src="https://www.raritanheadwaters.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/placeholder-picture-large-opt.png" alt="" /></p><p></p><h2>Buddy Up</h2><p></p><p>Invite someone to remix. You can be sounding boards that help one another open up. Start by identifying areas of improvement and telling each other what they are</p><p><a href="" target="_blank"></a></p></li>`

So it looks like it's just one <a tag and I'm also not getting the multiple ones.

Comment: Can you show me the output of `var_dump($linkPairs)` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220166/discussion-between-semir-smajlovic-and-jrswgtr).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you do not use html inside attributes, create for this one more attribute that will override the default value, I also added one more parameter for the link to the example:

Shortcode:

```
[myshortcode heading="Text of heading" heading_tag="h3" links="Name of link 1|#url1|blank, Name of Link2|#url2"]
```

and the handler itself

```
function linkParser($source) {
  $args = array_map('trim', explode('|',  trim($source)));
  $keys = ['url_name', 'url', 'target'];
  $results = [];
  foreach($args as $key => $value) {
    $results[(isset($keys[$key]) ? $keys[$key] : $key)] = $value;
  }
  return $results;
}
function myShortCode($attrs, $content = null) {
  $attrs = shortcode_atts([
    'heading_tag' => 'h2',
    "heading" => "",
    "links" => ""
  ], $attrs);

  $heading = sprintf('<%1$s>%2$s</%1$s>', (!empty($attrs['heading_tag']) ? $attrs['heading_tag'] : 'h2'), $attrs['heading']);

  $links = [];
  if(!empty($attrs['links'])) {
    $links = array_map('linkParser', explode(',', $attrs['links']));
  }

  // Tests with kint debug
  d($heading);
  d($links);
}

add_shortcode('myshortcode', 'myShortCode');
```

[image]

Comment: I agree about not using HTML in the attributes. Even better would be to not use any HTML in the PHP function either. Best would be to include a template partial in the function and pass the variables inside.

Comment: If there is a need to generate one title (as I did), then there is no point in using a template engine

Comment: But for rendering a full-fledged shortcode, it is naturally better to pass the data to the template engine

Comment: You only used a title, But the OP uses more HTML. Also a template engine would not be needed. A plain PHP (phtml) template would suffice